# Why is my text connected, and what is it called when this happens?

Tags: html, css

My font automatically does this. What is this called? How do I reproduce this with other text? How do I also get rid of it?

[image]

Comment: the font seems to be designed this way

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is a ligature (connecting the "c" to the "h"), they vary depending on the font (some have many, some have few or none). You can directly disable/enable ligatures with css [font-feature-settings](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/font-feature-settings/)

```
font-feature-settings: "liga" 0; /* disabled */
font-feature-settings: "liga" 1; /* enabled */
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cookie|Dancing+Script&display=swap');
span {
  font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive;
  font-size: 75px;
}

span.other {
  font-family: 'Cookie', cursive;
}

.with {
  font-feature-settings: "liga" 1;
}

.without {
  font-feature-settings: "liga" 0;
}
```

```html
<span class="with">
or ff
</span><br>
<span class="without">
or ff
</span>
<br>
<span class="other with">
or ff
</span><br>
<span class="other without">
or ff
</span>
```

There is also the css property [text-rendering](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-rendering/) that has some control over when ligatures are used or not.

Answer (score 0):

This is called a **[typographic ligature,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature)** and is built-in to certain fonts.

Specifically, the `fi` and `fl` ligatures are standard in Type 1 and TrueType fonts, though a broader range of standard ligatures are found in many of the new OpenType fonts.

You can add the style for other text by importing such a font, adding a **[`font-face`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face)** CSS rule which links to that font, and then referencing that particular font with **[`font-family`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-family)**:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: fancyFont;
  src: url(YOUR_FONT.woff);
}

p {
  font-family: "fancyFont", serif;
}
```